# I was deploying my python ML project on Heroku, got these errors

Tags: python, heroku, deploying

while I was developing in the Build main section got these errors

```
Collecting importlib==1.0.4
         Downloading importlib-1.0.4.zip (7.1 kB)
         Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
         Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
         error: subprocess-exited-with-error
         
         × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
         │ exit code: 1
         ╰─> [1 lines of output]
             ERROR: Can not execute `setup.py` since setuptools is not available in the build environment.
             [end of output]
         
         note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
       error: metadata-generation-failed
       
       × Encountered error while generating package metadata.
       ╰─> See above for output.
       
       note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
       hint: See above for details.
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

Comment: Hi @MFaisalQasim! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please refer to this post to see why you should not add words like "urgent" in your question: [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)

Answer (score 0):

I can see in the error this line: `ERROR: Can not execute setup.py since setuptools is not available in the build environment` which means you haven't added the `setuptools` module to the build environment of the project. Try to use `pip install setuptools` to install the module.

Comment: i have run this command, but its already there "Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\m faisal qasim\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (58.1.0)"

Comment: @MFaisalQasim what command did you use to run the Python program?

Comment: ```flask run```, the project runs fine on localhost it shows an error when I am deploying over Heroku. i am using Heroku GUI for deploying not cpmmands.